# Ember-data - Retrieve all types that extend DS.Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way of tell if a type extends DS.Model?

For example, I might have a class like this:

```
App.Klass = DS.Model.extend()
```

I want to say something like:

```
Ember.A(Ember.keys(Radium)).forEach (a) -> createType(a) instanceof DS.Model
```

The above will always be false because they are not instances.

Can anyone suggest a way of retrieving all the Model types from my an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `detect` method:

```
Ember.A(Ember.keys(Radium)).filter (a) -> DS.Model.detect(Radium[a])
```